# React HOC query graphql

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to query graphql in multiple pages in my app and I am trying to create a react higher order function to do so.

This is the original:

```
const Profiles = () => {
  // Omitted code
  const { loading, error, data, refetch, fetchMore } = useQuery(
    GET_PROFILES(),
    {
      variables: { id },
    }
  );

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  if (error) {
    // I need to find a way to eliminate this line because I am duplicating it on every page of my app
    if (error.message === '403: Forbidden' || error.message === '401: Unauthorized') {
      return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }

    return <Alert message="Error" description="Failed to load profiles." type="error" showIcon />;
  }

  return (
    <div>OMITTED</div>
  );
};
```

And this is what I currently have:

```
const WithQuery = (Comp, query, getVariables) => (props) => {
  const { loading, error, data, refetch, fetchMore } = useQuery(
    query(),
    {
      variables: getVariables(),
    }
  )

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  if (error) {
    // I need to find a way to eliminate this line because I am duplicating it on every page of my app
    if (error.message === '403: Forbidden' || error.message === '401: Unauthorized') {
      return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }

    return <Alert message="Error" description="Failed to load profiles." type="error" showIcon />;
  }

  return <Comp {...props} />
}

const Profiles = WithQuery(() => {
  return (
   const {id} - useContext(UserContext);
    <div>OMITTED</div>
  );
}, GET_PROFILES, () => ({ id }));
```

I am getting an error because of this `}, GET_PROFILES, () => ({ id }));` line id cannot be found. How can I send the hoc the id prop and also, how can I access data from the query inside of the div to be displayed?

Comment: Also can someone explain what does Comp, query, and getvariables do?

Comment: @suddjian basically I needed to reduce code duplication from the original because those same lines of code are displayed throughout the app. Someone answered a previous post of mine and I get some of it but Im confused about how to get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` isn't defined because it only exists in the context of your anonymous function component (the first argument to `WithQuery`. It can only be used inside the function in which it is defined.

You can actually use hooks in your `getVariables()` function, so it should be fixable by moving the `const {id} = useContext(UserContext)` line into the `() => ({ id })` function.

Comment: Thanks that worked, how can I access the data inside of the div?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with calling the `useContext` hook in both places where it's needed.